# Driving from Bulgaria to Greece

Tags: visas, car-rentals, borders, greece, bulgaria

I'm a US citizen driving from Bulgaria to Greece in a rented car. Where can I cross the border and what paperwork will I need?

Comment: In this case you have to take permission from the rental company that you are allowed to take the car to greece. No other documents are needed except the aggrement, driving liecence (better to have international) and the permission (which is nothing else than that they know you are taking the car to greece).

Comment: @NRandhawa Well, and a passport, obviously :-)

Answer (score 1):

As you are not the owner of the car, you will need a letter of authorization from the owner. Please contact the rental company for it and eypect to pay an additional fee for it.

Which border checkpoint to take depends on your starting point and your destination. The major one is Kulata - Promachonas.